# /etc/fstab mounting with auto buffer flushing

Tags: linux, fstab, sd-card, vfat, fat32

My `/etc/fstab` line for the SD I'm willing to mount looks like:

```
/dev/mmcblk1    /media/sd_card  vfat    user,rw,umask=000,sync  0 2
```

With this line I'm able to mount the SD, but everytime I want to unplug the SD I have to execute `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/mmcblk1` if I want to make the written changes take effect.

What means, that if I dont execute the `blockdev`-command all the written changes are lost after unplugging the SD.

The weird thing is, that I all the time I was using this line, I thought everything is working fine...

So what am I doing wrong?

---

I'm working on the jetson tx2 with Ubuntu 16.04 running on it.

Comment: unmounting the filesystem isn't enough?

Comment: @ilkkachu I can't say, when the user unplugs the SD. So I don't get your point.

Comment: Ah right, of course it doesn't help if you don't know when the card is unplugged. The phrasing in "everytime I want to unplug the SD I have to execute...", seemed to indicate that the intention to unplug was known in advance.